# I am not getting the Tree view when I create the .net core project in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am not getting the Tree view when I create the .net core project in Visual studio. Previously I have created the .net core in Visual studio Code.Now in Visual Studio, project structure is coming like what I got in VS Code.
I am getting folder structure like below image.

[image]

After toggling the folder icon on the top I got the structure as below image
[image]

I have .net core SDK version 2.1 and Visual studio 2017 Which I had was not supporting it.Just I updated the Visual studio 2017 Its working for me.

Comment: Click on the icon next to the `Home` icon above which says "Toggle folder/solution view". If I understand you correctly, this is what you want.

Comment: You are in folder mode. Double click on the sln file, or on the 4th button on the left.

Comment: I have tried it but its not working

Comment: It looks like you have a solution without any projects in it. How did you create it? Simplest solution is probably to right-click `Solution 'DummyTrial' (0 projects)` and select `Add` | `Existing Project`, and then just add your project.

Comment: As usually I created the project by opening file new Project .net core  and selecting Web API Project.I also tried adding project to the solution Its not working. I tried with different laptop and I am getting correct  tree  structure.@john

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have .net core SDK version 2.1 and Visual studio 2017 Which I had was not supporting it.Just I updated the Visual studio 2017 Its working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have the directory view selected in Solution Explorer. Click this button to toggle between the solution view and the directory view.

[image]